# We doing Bernoulli Experiment unlimited times

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

We are doing a Bernoulli Experiment with $P=0.4$ unlimited times.
What is the probability that we will get two successes before two failures?
(I need to solve it via conditional probability).

What I got is $p=\frac{4}{9}$, I'm right?
I say:
$E$ = We get two successes in sequence.
$F$ = We get success at the first time.
$G$ = We got success at the second time.
Now:
$$P(E)=P(E|F)\cdot P(F)+P(E|F^C)\cdot P(F^C)\\ =P(E|F) \cdot \frac25+P(E|F^C)\cdot \frac35$$
and then: $$P(E|F)=P(E|FG)\cdot P(G|F)+P(E|FG^C)\cdot P(G^C|F) \\ =1\cdot \frac25 + P(E)\cdot \frac35 \\-----------------------\\ P(E|F^C)=P(E|F^CG)\cdot P(G|F^C)+P(E|F^CG^C)\cdot P(G^C|F^C) \\ =P(E)\cdot \frac25+0 $$
Then we mark: $p=P(E)$ - $$p=(\frac25+\frac35p)\frac25 +\frac25p\Rightarrow p=\frac49$$

Thank you!

Comment: How did you get $p=\frac49$?

Comment: @V.C., I'm will wrote it...(it will take me few minutes).

Comment: @V.C. I put my solution... I hope is good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** We need to assume that the results of the experiment are independent.

The time may be unlimited, but the experiment will not take long.

Write S for success, and F for failure. The probability of S on any trial is $0.4$, and therefore the probability of F is $0.6$.

The only ways that we can have $2$ successes before $2$ failures are SS, SFS, and FSS.

Calculate. We get $\frac{2}{5}\cdot \frac{2}{5}+2\cdot\frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{3}{5}\cdot\frac{2}{5}=\frac{44}{125}$.

**Added:** We interpreted "two successes before two failures" to mean "a total of two successes before a total of two failures." But conceivably what is intended (and should have been said) is "What is the probability of two **consecutive** successes before two consecutive failures?"

Let $a$ be the probability we ultimately win, given that we have not yet won, but the last result we have is a success. Let $b$ be the probability that we ultimately win, given that we had not yet lost, but the last result was a failure.

By conditional probabilities, we have
$$a=\frac{2}{5}+\frac{3}{5}b$$
and 
$$b=\frac{2}{5}a.$$
So $a=\frac{10}{19}$ and $b=\frac{20}{95}$.

The probability we ultimately win is
$$\frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{10}{19}+\frac{3}{5}\cdot \frac{20}{95}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! It will help me a lot!!!

Comment: I don't understand how to you get it, but what happens if we get failure at the first attempt? I don't know how to explain it, but I think that there is something missing at your solution ... Thank you!

Comment: So, the final answer is: $\frac{32}{95}$?? I'm little bit confused...

Comment: But now - How you solve it with **conditional probability**? This is what I need...

Comment: So: W - We success at both. S - We success at the first. F - We failed at the first?

Comment: The question is: how do you get to those? $a=\frac{2}{5}+\frac{3}{5}b$ and $b=\frac{2}{5}a$, maybe this will give me the whole picture!

Comment: Let $W$ be the event we ultimately win. Let $S$ be the event we are one $S$ "ahead" and let $F$ be the event  are "behind". Let $a=\Pr(W|S)$ and let $b=\Pr(W|F)$. These are the $a$ and $b$ of the post, but we keep the conditional probability notation, since you prefer it.  Then $Pr(W|S)=2/5+(3/5)Pr(W|F)$. This is because if we are one S ahead, we either (i) get an S on the next try, and therefore win. This has probability $2/4$. **Or else**  (ii) we get an F, and are therefore behind. Given that, the probability we still win is $\Pr(W|F)$.  So the probability of (ii) is $(3/5)\Pr(W|F)$.(more)

Comment: (more) Add. We get $\Pr(W|S)=2/5+(3/5)\Pr(W|F)$. That's the first equation. The second equation is simpler. If we are "behind", te only way we can win is if we get an immediate S, getting "ahead", and then winning. So $\Pr(W|F)=(2/5)\Pr(W|S)$. The post then uses these two equations to find $\Pr(W|S)$ and $\Pr(W|F)$, that is, $a$ and $b$. Finally, we use the fairly obvious equation $Pr(W)=(2/5)Pr(W|S)+(3/5)Pr(W|F)$. And please do delete most of your comments.